# Read Data from Splunk using Spring

Tags: java, bigdata, spring-integration, splunk

I need to read a json that gets logged to splunk, parse it and store in a relational db.

I know how to parse the json, and do the post-processing. But, i am not quite sure how to extract data from splunk. What would be the best strategy and java technology stack for this use case? (The splunk sdk and rest api talks about running searches etc., but not data extraction itself. I see that spring-integration has some extensions for Splunk, so i might be able to use spring, but didn't find a concrete example for the same).

Comment: Running searches is a way of extracting data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for delay, indeed.

Yes, you definitely should use Spring Integration Splunk. According to the documentation of the last one to get data from there you should use the `search` functionality.

The Spring Integration Splunk provide the `<int-splunk:inbound-channel-adapter>` on the matter to retrieve `event`s from the Splunk and send them to the downstream integration flow.

Samples you can find in the test-cases of the project, but the simplest one may be like this:

```
<int-splunk:inbound-channel-adapter id="inboundChannelAdapter"
                                    splunk-server-ref="splunkServer"
                                    search="search host=SpringIO"
                                    channel="searchResults"
                                    mode="REALTIME"
                                    count="10"
                                    init-earliest-time="">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="100" max-messages-per-poll="1"/>
</int-splunk:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

The result of such an operation is `List<SplunkEvent>` as a `payload` of `Message<?>` sent to the `searchResults` `channel`.

Comment: Thanks @Artem Bilan. I ended up calling the splunk rest api directly, but yeah, Spring Integration Splunk should be the way to go.

Comment: Great! So, that sounds like a signal to accept the answer! :-)